# Conservation laws in probability and statistics

Tags: fluid-dynamics, statistical-mechanics, conservation-laws

Most of my research is confined to the field of continuum fluid mechanics, where conservation of mass, momentum, energy, etc. are commonly discussed. Often the variables under consideration represent the mean. I'm not well versed in the reach of conservation laws, but I do know that they are mathematical in nature. Is there a similar context of "conservation laws" in probability and statistics? I'm wondering if a more general statistical description of variables can be used as an alternative, while still adhering to conservation principles. For example, defining a velocity variable as the mean + standard deviation (as opposed to just the mean).  I tried to search "Conservation laws in probability and statistics" and didn't get much on the web, hence my question. Maybe I'm asking the wrong thing? Any insights welcome.

Comment: If you don't find an answer here in a couple days, you might want to try again over at [stats.se]

Answer (score 1):

From your question I am not sure what you are after, but here are two ideas that might go in the right direction:

1. Evolution equations for probability densities can (sometimes? often? - I don't know) be written as a conservation law. For example, a random walk can be described by a probability distribution $P$ that evolves in time according to
   $$
   \partial_t P + \nabla \cdot \vec{J}= 0
   $$
   with the probability current $\vec{J}$ chosen such that we obtain a Fokker-Planck equation,
   $$
   \vec{J} = - D^{(1)} P - D^{(2)} \cdot \nabla P\,.
   $$
2. Your sentence "For example, defining a velocity variable as the mean + standard deviation (as opposed to just the mean)." sounds like you might be interested in something like Reynolds averaging and the balance laws obtained from it, or even full-blown moment equations up to arbitrary order as used in statistical turbulence. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds-averaged_Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations Is that right?

Comment: "statistical turbulence" seems to be the words I was looking for